# calling a function from within a function

Tags: php

I have the following class-structures:

```
class SomeClass
{
    function execute()
    {
        $value = getValue();
    }

    function RegisterCallbackHandlers()
    {
        function ajaxCall()
        {
            $value = getValue();
        }
    }
}
```

The function **getValue** does the same for both instances it's called for but I can only get it to work for one at a time. When I put it within **execute** it works there. When I put it within **RegisterCallbackHandlers** it works for **ajaxCall**.

Where must I put it so it would work when called from **ajaxCall** and from **execute**?

Comment: Don't define a function within a function -- if you call the parent function a second time you'll get the fatal error "Cannot redeclare..."

Comment: the execute function executes on pageload, the RegisterCallbackHandlers function contains functions that are used for ajaxcalls from the page, this is on a framework I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed the **getValue** function in the **RegisterCallbackHandlers** function and call in it in the **execute** function like this:

```
SomeClass::RegisterCallbackHandlers();
$value = getValue($somNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a function inside a function, this function is NOT encapsulated.

So, `ajaxCall` is a global function that you can call everywhere and, most important, you can NOT redeclare it.

In fact if you do something of this:

```
$s = new SomeClass();
$s->RegisterCallbackHandlers();
$s->RegisterCallbackHandlers();
```

you got

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare ajaxCall()

So, you should call `RegisterCallbackHandlers` only one time, then you don't need to have any other declaration anywhere else.

Comment: RegisterCallbackHandlers will never be called twice, the containing functions are used for ajaxcalls only.

Comment: it was just an example. If you call `RegisterCallbackHandlers` one time, you don't need to redeclare the `ajaxCall` function, because it's already declared